# Mariadb check tables on startup

Tags: mariadb

Is there a way to have mariadb check tables in the background and not lock the tables after a crash? We have a number of fairly large databases and suffered a hardware failure that resulted in most of them checking tables on a restart which unfortunately blocked access to the databases for hours.

I get that a check is a good thing, however of all the databases, only one ended up needing to be fixed.

Ta.
Peter.

Comment: There is [no background check](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sql-commands-check-table/). /etc/mysql/debian-start runs mysqlcheck with `--all-databases --fast --silent`. Use InnoDB which is fault tolerant. Ensure to give it a decent innodb_buffer_pool_size, defaults are usually too small.

Comment: What sort of buffer_pool_size would you recommend (or is that a "how long is the piece of string" question)?

Comment: Look at the `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool%` and see how much is used and how much churn there is. At 100% used with a small amount of churn is ideal.

Comment: `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be set to 70% of _available_ RAM when using only InnoDB.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid the problem by switching your table from MyISAM to InnoDB.

Comment: They already are InnoDB.